# Evaluating integral with trigonometric function.

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following integral.

$$ \int 2^x~\tan^9(2^x)~\sec(2^x)~\mathrm{d}x $$

The homework hints say that i should make $u = 2^x$. I did but I couldn't continue.

Comment: What do you get after substituting $u=2^x$?

Comment: $\tan^9 u\sec u=\tan^8 u (\tan u\sec u)$. Write $tan^8 u$ in terms of $\sec u$ and let $s=\sec u$.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $ \sec^2(2^x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$u = 2^x$$ $$\frac{du}{u \ln2} = dx$$ $$ \frac{1}{\ln2} \int (\tan^2  u)^4 \tan  u \ \sec  u \ du $$

Now use $\tan^2 u = \sec^2 u - 1$ and then let $w = \sec \ u$

You should be able to get it to $$\frac{1}{\ln2}  \int (w^2 - 1)^4 dw$$

And from here it isn't so bad.

Comment: Please consider using \ln to get $\ln$ instead of $ln$, \tan to get $\tan$ instead of $tan$ and \sec to get $\sec$ instead of $sec$.

Comment: @Fly by Night , good ideas , thanx :)

Comment: So i will get $\frac{1}{ln2}\  \int v^6-4v^2-1\ dv $. But the answer in the book is $  \frac{1}{ln2} [\frac{1}{9} sec^9(2^x)-\frac{4}{7} sec^7(2^X)+ \frac{6}{5} sec^5(2^x)- \frac{4}{3} sec^3(2^x)+sec(2^x)]+ C $

Comment: @Tennisman , $(w^2 - 1)^4 = w^8 - 4w^6 + 6w^4 - 4w^2 + 1$ So if you integrate this then you should get the books answer. :)